# Can I create a OneToOne relationship with just the id?

Tags: java, jpa

In JPA is it possible to create an @OnToOne relationship with just an idea and not embedding the class? For example:

```
@Entity public class Relationship {
   @Id
   @OneToOne
   private Long parentId; // instead of "private User parent;"

   @Id
   @OneToOne
   private Long childId; // instead of "private User child;"

   int type;

   ...
```

I don't mind having a getter method with a lazy fetch but I don't need one and I'd prefer not to have to pull in complete parent objects to work with child objects. Also, I want to deserialize this to JSON using just the id and not the embedded object. I can do this by adding a getter that delegates to #getParent().getId() and putting a JsonIgnore on the #getParent() method (and the same for child) but I'd prefer to get the entity to look the way I want it to from the get go without adding this stuff. Possible and if so how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. How can an `Object` be related to a Number? This is an O-O language after all.

Labelling something as @OneToOne is semantically equivalent to a FK in the datastore. If you just omit @OneToOne and use a number then you have a numeric column in the datastore **without** a FK. So JPA allows both, but one gives the benefits of a FK, whereas with the other you just pass "numbers" around with no context of what they relate to

Comment: That JPA can't do this is a good enough answer. You've never heard of key/values, properties, etc in an O-O language? You can do this with a database, you can do this in just Java, you can do it in JDBC and with both, you just can't do it with JPA. That you can't because it is O-O is, well, a weak answer.

Comment: You _cannot_ do this exact thing in a database since when you have a FK you have the table you're linking to, and with @OneToOne on a number you have no such "type" that it relates to (i.e the related class). Obviously you could just persist a number, and dump the FKs from your datastore but then that throws away lots of benefits ...

Comment: I think you're splitting hairs. In a database OR an O-O language you can relationship to a typed identity. In a database this could be a FK and in an O-O language it could be an Object reference handled by the runtime or a Typed Identity that is coded where a UID of some type (number, string, or whatever) is encapsulated within an instance of the typed identity class.

Comment: @user1888440: In database you also define related table while defining FK. Similarly in ORM you would need related Class to define relationship. To me OO is a fair and valid point. Your point about JDBC sounds invalid because JDBC is not really OO but reading fields individually.